Delete Google account users in Firebase
I have an app in Flutter with Firebase login, I provide the option to delete a regular user with email and password but how can I delete a user that signed in with Google, should I deal with it or tell them to go to Google and remove my app if they want to get deleted? is it in Google Play's policy to enable this sort of functionality?

You can delete the current user account by using below code.
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!

user.delete()
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.")
        }
    }


I get the error that the user needs to reauthenticate his credentials.

You can make every users log out and then make them log in again

Assuming you have already deleted the Firebase user by calling await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete();
The next step will be to call await GoogleSignIn().disconnect(); with the Flutter Google SignIn plugin.
This should disconnect the current user from the app, revoke previous authentication and remove the scopes that the user authorized earlier.

But I can't call await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete(); because the user is not recently authenticated.

I made an assumption. You did not provide a code showing how you are deleting the Firebase user, but nevertheless, you should use the GoogleSignIn().disconnect(); to disassociate a user's Google account from your app after you have deleted the Firebase user. @Tevel


I provide the option to delete a regular user with email and password but how can I delete a user that signed in with Google

There is no difference between providers. When you delete a user from the Firebase Authentication, it doesn't matter if the user has signed in with email and password or Google. If you delete a user that signed in with Google, you basically delete the Firebase user account, not the Google account itself.

Hey Tevel. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
